# Application stops for unknown reason when playing with visuals in "File Watcher" method

Tags: c#, winforms

In my WinForms c# application I've created a method, which starts when a .mp4 file is created in a specified folder. To do this I run the following code:

```
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
        watcher.Path = @"D:\transcoderen";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_FileCreated);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

And eventually the method:

```
    void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

This code works almost completely. When a .mp4 file is created in D:\transcoderen, the method starts.
But for some unknown reason the application stops running when I change visible states of a control, in my example a pictureBox control. When I'm debugging in Visual Studio 2010, it just stops when it hits:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = false;
```

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't give an error or anything. It acts the same as when i click the "Stop debugging" button.
Has anybody encountered this problem before? If you do so, is there a work around to achieve this?

I think it gets stuck for some reason, maybe it has something to do with the fact that this method watches for files.

Thanks in advance,

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the FileWatcher event is raised from a different thread. You have to check if the pictureBox1 requires an Invoke using [Control.InvokeRequired Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) and then call [trol.BeginInvoke Method (Delegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx)

Also have a look at [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)